# Is it possible to load a database scheme with config file on a redis database hosted with docker?

Tags: database, docker, redis

I hosted a redis database with docker and now I want to know if it is possible to load the database scheme with a config file I will save in my repository?
Thanks for your help

Comment: The scheme tag is for the scheme programming language.

Comment: Redis doesn't have schemas.  It's a flat key/value space with a couple of possible types of values.

Answer (score 1):

If the image you use has the ability to load external file, then it will be a matter to provide the file to the container when you create container.

The official redis image allows you to give your own config file as well as mount a file storage area.

What you need to do is:

1. Create folder in your repository ex. `redis`
2. Create configuration and data folders under it ex `redis/config` and `redis/data`
3. Create the `redis.conf` in `redis/config` to enable the persistence as follows:

   ```
   SAVE 60 1
   dbfilename initial_file.rdb
   dir /data
   ```
4. Start container with redis as follows

   ```
   $ docker run -v <repo folder>/redis/conf:/usr/local/etc/redis -v <repo folder>/redis/data:/data -d --name some-redis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
   ```
5. Enter in to the container and initialize the database

   ```
   $ docker exec -ti some-redis /bin/bash
   root@4ec2d5dc5082:/data# redis-cli
   127.0.0.1:6379> set test 1
   OK
   127.0.0.1:6379> save
   OK
   ```

   you can initialize the database with file as well, just copy the file to the container and use the cli tools to load the file.
6. Stop the container and clean

   ```
   $ docker stop some-redis
   $ docker rm some-redis
   ```
7. Add the new files to your repository and commit the changes

After this you will have the database files in your repository. Whenever you want to use them, you can start a container as in step 4